# Submit an app created with create-react-native-app to the App Store (without XCode?)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, create-react-native-app

**Before, react-native 0.45**, when you'd create a project, it would generate a XCode project file in the ios folder so that you can open it with XCode and use it to submit your app to the app store.

**Since react-native 0.45**, react native project are created with the `create-react-native-app` command and there is no xcode project anymore.

I read that you can "eject" to go back to the old style and get an XCode project. `create-react-native-app` is supposed to make everything easier, so I suppose there is a way to submit to the app store without ejecting that doesn't make the whole process much more painful than by using XCode.

To be clear: I understand that there are probably ways to submit to the app store without XCode, but aren't them much more painful? I can't believe that react-native would then consider it an improvement to not generate a XCode project anymore.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: [Create React Native App does a lot of work to make app setup and development simple and straightforward, but it's very difficult to do the same for deploying to Apple's App Store or Google's Play Store without relying on a hosted service.](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/react-native-scripts/template/README.md#sharing-and-deployment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since react-native 0.45, react native project are created with the create-react-native-app command and there is no xcode project anymore.

This is incorrect. `create-react-native-app` is simply one of two ways to start a React Native project. The `react-native init` method of starting a project is [still there in the docs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/getting-started.html).

> To be clear: I understand that there are probably ways to submit to the app store without XCode, but aren't them much more painful? I can't believe that react-native would then consider it an improvement to not generate a XCode project anymore.

You are not going to get a good answer for this as it's very much down to opinion.

> Could someone point me in the right direction?

As a starting point for learning how to publish, I suggest looking at the [create-react-native-app documentation](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app#how-do-i-get-my-app-into-the-play-storeapp-store) as it gives you two options right there:

1. [Ejecting](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md) to generate the `ios` and `android` folders with which you can then publish.
2. Using a third party service like [Expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v13.0.0/guides/building-standalone-apps.html) to publish for you.

Their [documentation](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/react-native-scripts/template/README.md#sharing-and-deployment) goes a bit more into depth on the options. This is the best summary I can give as an answer without putting any of my opinions into it.